# Picasso download random image

Tags: android, random, picasso

in my new app, at some point I need to fetch a random image (i use this [link](http://unsplash.it/200/?random)) using Picasso. The problem is even if I set the network policy to no cache the image stays the same if I exit the activity and relaunch it.
Note it's the second activity that contains this Picasso downloading

Answer (score 2):

Refer [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-influencing-image-caching) its well explained here!

Summarizing: Use `NetWorkPolicy` along with `MemoryPolicy`

```
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[2])
    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
    .into(imageViewFromNetwork);
```

Comment: My pleasure! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a random value to your url.

Example :

```
http://unsplash.it/200/?random=<a random value computed each time>
```